# Need help boxing Divs html

Tags: html

Im trying to get my colored div boxes side by side, but I am having trouble with my lower two divs. The yellow div is over the blue one. How can I get it side by side like my green and red one? Does my issue pertain to how I am floating everything? I'm required to complete this task without using a linked css document.

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: crimson;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}


}
div.div3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}

}
div.div4 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 425px;
  width: 425px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">


</div>

<div class="div2">

</div>
<div>
  <div class="div3">

    <div class="div4">


    </div>
```

here is what my output looks like. The yellow div is over the blue one.

[image]

I'm trying to get my divs to look similar to this picture.

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the formatted snippet I made, your HTML is not correct and neither is the CSS

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the float it will look like this after closing the divs and removing extra `}`:

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: crimson;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}

div.div3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}

div.div4 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #888888;
}
.break { clear:left }
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 430px;
  width: 430px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  </div>

  <br class="break" />

  <div class="div3">
  </div>
  <div class="div4">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is a mess. You don't need seporate style tags for each div. I would recommend using `absolute` and `relative` positioning instead of floating. Just put each div under the class `box` and give that the following styles:

```
div.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And select each one individually either using id's or using the `nth-of-type()` selector, like this:

```
div.box:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: crimson;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

And finally wrap the `box`'s in a div and give that the class `container` and give it the following styles:

```
div.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 425px;
  width: 425px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
div.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 425px;
  width: 425px;
  position: relative;
}
div.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: crimson;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.box:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/eGKxzB)

Comment: Just closing the divs and removing the extra brackets helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage `inline-block` for this.

```css
.mainbox {
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <div class="row-1">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-2">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```